# How to delete tomcat8 and related files like docs examples admin?

Tags: tomcat8

I installed tomcat8 and then tried to use tomcat8-docs webapp manager but link did not work.

Can you please guide me to uninstall completely tomcat8 along with docs examples admin and other files.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to add your Ubuntu release and explain how you installed Tomcat in the first place? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow this on the command line**

```
sudo apt remove --purge tomcat8 tomcat8-docs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Use the above to purge any app from your system including config files.

Once this is complete you can use something like find or locate to remove any remaining stragglers.

```
sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb
locate tomcat
```

And you can manually delete anything that might remain.